# Is it possible to pretty-print a JSDOM document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am working on dynamically building an HTML output file in a NodeJS application. While working in development, I want this file to be pretty-printed so I can inspect the output better. Here is what I've got so far, it's very bare bones because I'm still figuring out how I want to do this:

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><head /><body /></html>');
const document = dom.window.document;

const css = `
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
`;

const createElement = ({ tagName, textContent }) => {
    const elem = document.createElement(tagName);
    elem.textContent = textContent;
    return elem;
};

document.head.appendChild(createElement({ 
    tagName: 'title', 
    textContent: 'Shopping List'
}));
document.head.appendChild(createElement({
    tagName: 'style',
    textContent: css
}));

console.log(dom.serialize()); // TODO delete this
```

As you can see, I'm logging the output of dom.serialize(), which gives me a string version of the HTML I am building with my JS code. The thing is, it's all one-lined like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Shopping List</title><style>
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style></head><body></body></html>
```

The only line breaks come from my literal CSS that I'm adding. What I want is to serialize and print this all out in a way that effectively pretty-prints it, ie includes line breaks and indenting. This is for development only, so that I can more easily read the output as I debug it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an npm package called [pretty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty).

```js
var pretty = require('pretty');

pretty(STRING_OF_HTML);
```

Before

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>Home</title> 
</head> <body> This is content. </body> </html>
```

After

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is content.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that lib is just a wrapper for https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify, for thous who want more options

Answer (score 3):

By using Prettier:

```js
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import prettier from "prettier";

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Documentation</title></head><body/></html>`);

const resultHtml = dom.serialize();
const formattedHtml = await prettier.format(resultHtml, { parser: "html" });
console.log(formattedHtml)
```

Will print

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Documentation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: `prettier.format()` returns a promise. You should probably write `const formattedHtml = await prettier.format(resultHtml, { parser: "html" });` instead